# Session name is not retrieved in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, hyperlink, master-pages

i using a **single master page** in asp.net for log-In and Log-Out functionality...
but in master page **session name** takes null value.
Here is my code ,please help me...
**MasterPage.master.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (!IsPostBack)
          {
             if (Session["name"] == null)
                {
                  Panel2.Visible = false;
                  Panel1.Visible = true;
                }
             else if (Session["name"] != null)
                    {
                      Panel1.Visible = false;
                      Panel2.Visible = true;
                      Label2.Text = "WELCOME | Mr." + Session["name"].ToString();
                    }
          }
      }
        protected void LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               Session.Clear();
               Session.Abandon();
            }
```

my **homepage.aspx.cs**

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string st="select Label4,Label3 FROM Register1_master WHERE Label4='" +        TextBox1.Text + "' and Label3='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(st, sqlcon);
      cmd.Connection.Open();
      string result= null;
      Object value=cmd.ExecuteScalar ();
      if ( value != null)
       {
          result = value.ToString ();
          Session["name"] = TextBox1.Text;
          Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
       }
         else
          {
            Label3.Text="Invalid username or password";
          }
            cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
```

after the login from homepage i'll be go on **Main.aspx** page

my **Main.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         if (!IsPostBack) 
           {
            HyperLink link = (HyperLink)Master.FindControl("HyperLink1");
            link.Visible = false;
            HyperLink link1 = (HyperLink)Master.FindControl("HyperLink2");
            link1.Visible = true;
            Label masterlbl = (Label)Master.FindControl("Label2");
            string login = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]);
            Session["name"] = login;

           }

       }
```

Comment: F9 on --> Session["name"] = TextBox1.Text;
F9 also on --> Session["name"] = login;

are you sure you hit this statement? What are the values?

Comment: Are you sure you have sessionstate enabled in your project? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: please use string st="select * FROM Register1_master WHERE Label4='" +        TextBox1.Text + "' and Label3='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

Comment: actually i did that...
but session["name"] gives a null value.
i think in single master page this is very typical ...
Infer-On

Comment: In line 'string st="select Label4,Label3 FROM Register1_master WHERE Label4='" +   '.... are you sure that "+" is appropriate?

Comment: You have an SQL injection problem in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try like this :

```
  int result= null;
  result= = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value (for example, an aggregate value) from a database. This requires less code than using the ExecuteReader method, and then performing the operations that you need to generate the single value using the data returned by a SqlDataReader.

A typical ExecuteScalar query can be formatted as in the following C# example:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.region";
 Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Please refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)